# 'For in' no me reconoce los elementos en una array

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente problema con un bucle 'for in':  no me quiere reconocer los elementos de la array. He intentado ver los elementos despues de llamar al 'for in' con el console.log , pero me devuelve 0 .

```js
function isValidWalk(walk) {
    console.log(walk.length);
    if (walk.length ===10) { 
        var WalkN=[]; 
        var WalkS=[];
        var WalkE=[];
        var WalkW=[];
        console.log(walk);
        for (var elemento in walk) { 
            console.log(elemento);
            console.log(walk);
            switch (elemento) { 
                case 'n':
                 WalkN.push(elemento);
                 break;
                case 's':
                 WalkS.push(elemento);
                 break;
                case 'e':
                 WalkE.push(elemento);
                 break;
                case 'w':
                 WalkW.push(elemento);
            }
        console.log( WalkN,WalkS,WalkE,WalkW);
         if (WalkN.length===WalkS.length && WalkE.length===WalkW.length) {
             return true
         }
         else { return false }
        }
    }
    else {
        return false 
    }
}
isValidWalk(['n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s'])
```

Comment: Deberias incluir un ejemplo del array `walk`

Comment: Si , lo siento , lo acabo de añadir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más fácil de tener lo que quieres en un ciclo foreach es cambiar el

```
in
```

por un

```
of
```

de tal manera que quedaría casi tal cual como lo tienes.

```
function isValidWalk(walk) {
    console.log(walk.length);
    if (walk.length ===10) { 
        var WalkN=[]; 
        var WalkS=[];
        var WalkE=[];
        var WalkW=[];
        console.log(walk);
        for (var elemento of walk) { 
            console.log(elemento);
            console.log(walk);
            switch (elemento) { 
                case 'n':
                 WalkN.push(elemento);
                 break;
                case 's':
                 WalkS.push(elemento);
                 break;
                case 'e':
                 WalkE.push(elemento);
                 break;
                case 'w':
                 WalkW.push(elemento);
            }
        console.log( WalkN,WalkS,WalkE,WalkW);
         if (WalkN.length===WalkS.length && WalkE.length===WalkW.length) {
             return true
         }
         else { return false }
        }
    }
    else {
        return false 
    }
}
isValidWalk(['n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s'])
```

de esa manera puedes acceder al contenido del array y no al índice.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que `for..in` no esta diseñado para arrays sino para objetos.  Para objener el resultado que deseas, es mejor usar `forEach` asi:

```js
function isValidWalk(walk) {
    console.log(walk.length);
    if (walk.length ===10) { 
        var WalkN=[]; 
        var WalkS=[];
        var WalkE=[];
        var WalkW=[];
        console.log(walk);
        walk.forEach(function(elemento) { 
            console.log(elemento);
            console.log(walk);
            switch (elemento) { 
                case 'n':
                 WalkN.push(elemento);
                 break;
                case 's':
                 WalkS.push(elemento);
                 break;
                case 'e':
                 WalkE.push(elemento);
                 break;
                case 'w':
                 WalkW.push(elemento);
            }
            
            if (WalkN.length===WalkS.length && WalkE.length===WalkW.length) {
              return true
            }
            else { return false }
        });
        console.log( WalkN,WalkS,WalkE,WalkW);
    } else {
        return false 
    }
}
isValidWalk(['n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer de esta manera también:

```
var mi_array =  ['n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s'];
 isValidWalk(mi_array);

 function isValidWalk(walk) {
    if (walk.length == 10) { 
    var WalkN = []; 
    var WalkS = [];
    var WalkE = [];
    var WalkW = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < walk.length; i++){ 

        switch (walk[i]) { 
            case 'n':
             WalkN.push(walk[i]);
             break;
            case 's':
             WalkS.push(walk[i]);
             break;
            case 'e':
             WalkE.push(walk[i]);
             break;
            case 'w':
             WalkW.push(walk[i]);
        }

     if (WalkN.length == WalkS.length && WalkE.length == WalkW.length) {
         return true
     }
     else { return false }
    }
}
else {
    return false 
}
}
```